# Proving that a function from $N\times N$ to $N$ is bijective.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am stuck on this problem:

Define $f: N\times N \rightarrow N$ by

$f(i,j)=\frac{(i+j-1)(i+j-2)}{2}+i$.

How do you prove that $f$ is a bijection thus $N\times N$ and $N$ are numerically equivalent?

Work: First I tried to prove that $f$ is injective by setting $f(i,j)=f(x,y)$. However, from here I am stuck and I cannot reduce it properly. My work really does not get anywhere significant and its really messy.

Comment: Note that $f(0,0)=1=f(1,0)$.

Comment: You should add to your work the part where you search the website for the several times where this function was discussed in more and in less details.

Comment: @vadim123: If I recall correctly, the formulation of the function in this case is suitable for the case where $0$ is not included in the natural numbers.

Comment: Yes, I believe that $N$ in this case does not include $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f(i,j) = f(k,\ell)$. You must show that $i = k$ and $j = \ell$.

First show that $i+j = k+\ell$. This can be done by contradiction: Let's assume WLOG $i+j > k+\ell$. Set $m = k+\ell$ and $i+j = m + r$, where $r > 0$. Now work out $f(i,j) - f(k,\ell)$ with these new variables and show that this difference must be positive, if $r > 0$. Therefore $i+j \le k+\ell$. This step is somewhat tricky.

Next show that also $i = k$. This step is not hard.

Finally show that $j = \ell$. This step is very easy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. However, I cannot get past the first step as I cannot prove that the difference must be positive.

Comment: Please send me an email, from your university account.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my hint. Note that $f(i, j) = \binom{i+j-1}{2} + i$. So while $f(j, i)$ will hold the same binomial term, it will change the constant we add to $j$ instead of $i$. So $f(2, 3) = \binom{4}{2} + 2$, while $f(3, 2) = \binom{4}{2} + 3$.

Once you simplify like this, it should make it much easier to prove an injection.